# Unknown column 'work_order_id' in 'field list' while inserting data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, postman

I got this error while I run my PHP page in Postman. I don't know what mistake I did.

Here, I am trying to insert the id of the workordername into the `ticket_raising table`.

`work_order_id` is the foreign key in the `ticket_raising` table.

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$workordername = $_POST["workordername"];
$workorderid = mysqli_query($conn,"select `work_order_id` from `workorder_category` where `workorder_name` = '$workordername'");
$submitted_on = $_POST["submitted_on"];
$status = $_POST["status"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$notes = $_POST["notes"];


$mysql_query = "insert into ticket_raising(work_order_id,submitted_on,status,subject,notes) values ('$workorderid','$submitted_on','$status','$subject','$notes') ";
if ($conn->query($mysql_query)==TRUE) {
    echo "insert successfully";
}
else {
    echo "error:".$mysql_query."<br>".$conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
 ?>
```

I am adding table schemas of `ticket_raising` and `workorder_category` here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjg9j.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsRLh.png

Any suggestive examples for inserting the foreign key into the table that would make my learning easier.

Comment: Can you share your table layout? Are you sure that the referenced column really exists?

Comment: update your question and add  the table ticket_raising schema

Comment: I have updated the question by adding table layouts @Nico Hasse

Comment: Obviously you won't because you are not storing any valid 
 value in `$workorderid` after you make your query, you have to retrive the `$workorderid` first and then stored in a `$workorderid`

Comment: @Machavity why is this a mix of apis? I don't see it, unless you know something I don't, *lol!*

Comment: It's a typo question and voted to close accordingly, not as mixing mysql apis as originally closed which were wrong.

Comment: This code is a complete mess

Answer (score 1):

You try to insert into field `work_order_id` but your scheme image shows field name `word_order_id`.

Seems like a typo when you created the field name?
ie
Schema is: wor**D**_order_id
SQL is: wor**K**_order_id

So you either need to update your scheme to change it to `work_order_id` or change your code to `insert into word_order_id`. If you change the scheme you'll have to change all scripts where this field name is currently referenced.

Comment: If that means I should change work_order_ id as the foreign key?